# Как посмотреть значение переменной окружения в windows?

Tags: windows

Как посмотреть значение переменной окружения в windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого надо открыть консоль и выполнить команду

```
set VAR_NAME
```

На экране появится надпись

```
VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE
```

если переменная установлена или сообщение о том, что переменная не установлена.

Answer (score 4):

Мой компьютер - Свойства - Дополнительные параметры системы - Переменные среды